# Why do my popup window collide with my ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, event-handling

Hey this is part of a program i´m writing for school and for some reson my popup window "event addCustomer" collides with the line:
customersList.setItems(oList);

in the method setListView() at the bottom?
any ideas?
If u need the rest of the program i can post it on request!

Thankful for help!

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private BankLogic b;

    private ObservableList<String> oList;

    @FXML
    private ListView customersList;

    @FXML
    private Button addCustomerButton, deleteCustomerButton;

    @FXML
    private Button confirmPop1, cancelPop1, confirmPop2, cancelPop2;


    @FXML
    private void addCustomer(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Stage stage;
        Parent root;

        stage = new Stage();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLpopUp1.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(addCustomerButton.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.showAndWait();
    } // opens a confirm window with 2 buttons:

    @FXML
    private void confirmPop1(ActionEvent event) {

        Stage stg = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stg.close();

    }

    @FXML
    private void cancelPop1(ActionEvent event) {

        Stage stg = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stg.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        b = BankLogic.getInstance();


        long nr = 198905643943L;
        b.addCustomer("Kalle karlsson", nr); 
        nr = 198905643843L;
        b.addCustomer("Peter haraldsson", nr);
        nr = 198967643943L;
        b.addCustomer("Hans haraldsson", nr);
        nr = 198905643978L;
        b.addCustomer("Harry haraldsson", nr);
       // 4 objects of a class called Customer!

        setListView(); // calling method to fill ListView 

    }

    public void setListView() {  
        oList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ArrayList<Customer> tC = b.getCustomerList();
        for (Customer c : tC) {
            String s = c.getName() + " " + c.getPnr();
            oList.add(s);
        }

        customersList.setItems(oList); // This line collides with my popup window and givs me an exception.
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 45 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: file:/NetBeansProjects/Grupp1-Bank/dist/run1287972729/BankSystem.jar!/banksystem/FXMLpopUp1.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at banksystem.FXMLDocumentController.addCustomer(FXMLDocumentController.java:86)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at banksystem.FXMLDocumentController.setListView(FXMLDocumentController.java:193)
at banksystem.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:180)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
... 63 more
```

Comment: From the stack trace, it appears you get a null pointer exception when the `FXMLpopUp1.fxml` file is loaded, when the `initialize()` method calls `setListView()`. But it looks like that FXML file is being loaded from this controller (in `addCustomer()`). Are you using the same controller class for two different FXML files? (And if so, why???)

Comment: Yes i´m using the same controller! the FXMLpopUp1.fxml is just a window with a confirm button and a cancel button, but i want to be able to do different things in this controller depending on the answer!  I don´t understand why that should cause a collide like this. I should add that this happens when i click the button and if i remove the line:  customersList.setItems(oList); The popup window works fine!

Comment: Well, you're not using the same controller, but both your controllers are (for reasons known only to you) from the same class. Presumably your `FXMLpopUp1.fxml` doesn't have a control with `fx:id="customersList`", so in that controller `customersList` is null, and when that controller's `initialize()` method calls `setListView()` you get a null pointer exception. Even if you used the same actual controller instance, you wouldn't want to reset `customersList` when you loaded the second FXML. Use a different controller class for each FXML file.

Comment: (As an aside, the word "collide" does not mean what you think it means: not sure what you intend to say there.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick answer i will try to create a new controller for FXMLpopUp1.fxml, sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading two different FXML files and consequently two different controllers are created for you. It appears from the stack trace that you have configured things so that both controllers are from the same class.

When the `FXMLLoader` loads the FXML file and creates the controller instance, it injects fields annotated `@FXML` with elements in the FXML file with matching `fx:id` attributes, and then calls the `initialize()` method.

Your `FXMLpopUp1.fxml` appears not to have any element with a `fx:id="customersList"`, so `customersList` remains null in that controller. Consequently you get a null pointer exception when the `initialize()` method calls `setListView()`.

You should use different controller classes for each FXML file. The controller class for `FXMLpopUp1.fxml` might look something like

```
public class PopupController {

    @FXML
    private Button confirmPop ;

    private boolean confirmed = false ;

    public void isConfirmed() {
        return confirmed ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void confirmPop() {
        confirmed = true ;
        confirmPop.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

    @FXML
    private void cancelPop() {
        confirmed = false ;
        confirmPop.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

and then in your "main" controller you could do

```
@FXML
private void addCustomer(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    Stage stage;
    Parent root;

    stage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLpopUp1.fxml"));
    root = loader.load();
    PopupController popupController = loader.getController();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(addCustomerButton.getScene().getWindow());
    stage.showAndWait();
    if (popupController.isConfirmed()) {
        // confirm button was pressed...
    }
}
```